# Consistent failure to upgrade from 5.25.0 to 5.28.x

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, 5.25

I try to follow  https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/ to upgrade from 5.25 to 5.28.n as 5.25 is broken in WP5.5

After the step    Point your web browser to the following URL

http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1

I consistently get this error despite following the instructions to the letter. I have no extra extensions, on the face of it, this would seem a fairly straightforward process.

````
#0 /home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(337): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(82): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 5.25.0")
#2 /home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(57): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->runIntro()
#3 /home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->run((Array:2), NULL)
#4 /home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#5 /home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#6 /home/customer/www/staging21.example.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1601): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#7 /home/customer/www/staging21.example.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#8 /home/customer/www/staging21.example.org/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#9 /home/customer/www/staging21.example.org/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#10 /home/customer/www/staging21.example.org/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(254): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#11 {main}

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/customer/www/example.org/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php:478) in /home/customer/www/staging21.example.org/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9

WordPress 5.5 is available! Please update now.
 Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 5.25.0 ```


 Any hints welcome...  I get this with 5.28.0 and 5.28.3 over past couple of days.
````

Comment: This might seem a stupid question but have you substituted example.org for the name of your site when running the URL http://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1  ?  The reason I'm asking is that example.org appears all through your error statement above.

Comment: Yes - well spotted   - Im obfuscating the name of the organisation I am doing this for :-)

Only stupid question is the one you didn't ask.....

Answer (score 1):

```
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
```

Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 5.25.0

This message indicates that the CiviCRM version installed is 5.25, not 5.28.3  Can you double check that you have replaced all the files in the `plugins/civicrm` folder?  You should make a backup, remove the folder and then extract the new zip file.   That way there are no leftover files from prior versions hanging around.

Comment: I deleted all in plugins/civicrm again and unzipped the 5.28.3 archive. I double checked that I had thre correct version
'code` baseos | u651-sqblahhega2@blah.siteground.eu:/home/customer/www/staging21.blah.blah/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm$ less civicrm.php 
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: CiviCRM
Description: CiviCRM - Growing and Sustaining Relationships
Version: 5.28.3
Requires at least: 4.9
Requires PHP:      7.1


still get the same error sadly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the civicrm your civicrm plugin is 5.28.x version and you have only single civicrm folder in plugins (no backups, no renamed folders etc)

Comment: Still getting the same error. I have deleted CiviAdmin and CF CiviCRM plugins.   Makes no difference at all...

Comment: Are you doing this on test site or live?

Comment: a test site, sir.

Comment: Can you check uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php file is using correct path for $civicrm_root variable?

Comment: $civicrm_root = '/home/customer/www/blah.blah/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';

Comment: is that test site path to civi?

Comment: I'd like to move this to chat but I only have +13 reputation
I am obfuscating the name of the org involved.
Can yo ask the question a little more clearly, please. I am - obviously, a novice at this, sorry.

Comment: /home/customer/www/blah.blah/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ is this path to your test civicrm plugin?

Comment: yes that is correct - I have followed the official docs precisely.  I have no extensions and have also installed the i10n files for en_gb